# Remotely Deploy SSIS Packages From Computer that Doesn't Have SSIS Installed

Tags: ssis

In order to improve the customer install experience of my companies software, I'm trying to figure out a way to remotely deploy SSIS packages from a computer that doesn't have SSIS installed. I would like to eliminate the need for the customer to run the installer on both the app and SQL/SSIS servers. Is this possible from either a tool or programmatically? I tried to programmatically deploy the packages with the Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS library but received an exception that the "Integration Services class cannot be found". Since I'm able to run the database scripts using System.Data.SqlClient classes from a computer that doesn't have SQL installed, I was hoping that there is something similar for SSIS. Currently the software needs to support SQL Server versions 2008-2012.